# How to prevent some files outgoing uploads with Ubuntu? (catch outgoing request and reject it)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, sftp

The problem is, that my IDE automatically uploads any files from project folder.
There is no way to configure exclusion- to say it "Don't upload specific files/file types"

Are there any tools in Ubuntu to catch outgoing ftp/sftp requests and reject them,
or better to emulate successfull transfer ? (maybe, to run my bash script on transfer start and reject)

Something like event handler "OnTransferStart", where i can simply run my code and return false/true to reject/allow;
Or something like table of rules for file paths/types.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the IDE editing the files, so you can't stop IDE from reading the file.

It will be easy if stopping **all** Internet connection of the IDE is considerable.

If not, there may not be an easy way. When IDE uploads the files, there's two steps:

1. Load the file. You can monitor when IDE reads the specific files. When IDE does, wake the network monitor.
2. Upload the content. We can only see the data to be uploaded, but maybe can't see the filename. So we can only monitor the network traffic, stop those which has the same content with the specific files.

But step 2 is pretty tricky:

1. If the IDE uploader uses HTTPS, you need to create a local certificate.
2. If the IDE **encrypts** the data, you can never find it out - since you don't want to cut the IDE whole out of the Internet.

Comment: Anyway, I would like to have possibility to catch step #2, and test upload contents with my bash script or any program.
I suppose, IDE uses SFTP protocol, according to ps ax | grep ftp

Comment: @ИванДоронин That's smart - I haven't thought of this. It is quite much easier.

Comment: couldn't you advice any specific tools to monitor traffic and handle it?

Comment: @IvanDoronin I haven't done this kind of thing before. This more like a `firewall`, maybe IPTables?